# WebClient construction overhead

Tags: c#, webclient

I have a client which makes a limited number of concurrent web requests. I use WebClient for this purpose. I currently have a pool of WebClient-s which I create once and use whichever one is idle.

This approach is becoming a little cumbersome though, and I'm wondering if there is any benefit to having a collection of pre-constructed WebClient instances, or if creating them on the fly wouldn't be too much trouble?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why on earth would you have a pool of WebClients in the first place? They are tiny, cheap objects. Did you determine by measuring that this is needed and beneficial? I assume not?

Object instantiation is almost always cheap. HTTP connections are not expensive, either. A WebClient pool is premature optimization. There is no need for it - feel free to create as many as you want.

Comment: Well, that was the question I was asking - is it worth having a pool. Thanks for answering it. :p

Comment: "Object instantiation is almost always cheap." that is not true. Maybe relatively cheap, relatively to business or WCF tasks, but for perfomance critical application that is very significant.  Some time ago I have made some app with a lot of "simple" objects initialization in C#. Then I have rewritten it in C and got 4x performance improvement after I have rewrite it in C but this time without  "simple" objects initialization (reusing objects) and got 3X perfomance grouth (relative t o old C version) that is 12X over C#. Not much?

Comment: That's kind of the point. When there is a performance concern, you can determine whether an optimization is needed and/or genuinely beneficial by measuring performance.

Answer (score 9):

According to Reflector all that the constructor of WebClient does is this:

```
public WebClient()
{
    this.m_Encoding = Encoding.Default;
    this.m_ContentLength = -1L;
}
```

So no you have not much benefit of having a pool.

Comment: There could be expensive lazy initialization elsewhere.

Comment: Also, `WebClient` is a `Component`, which is 'IDisposable'.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 4.0 you can parallelize the Web Requests. Check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/19/9791857.aspx) out.

But to the real question, I wouldn't store the instances of the WebClient in an Array, if there is no need to re-use that instance on other places. Depending on the purpose and the kind of usage you could aswell have a Request Pool with a String Dictionary.

And then just re-use a WebClient instead of having multiple instances.